# Automatic REST API generation for CRUD for MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, orm

I have *mongodb* database with several collections (more than 50). I want to create *CRUD REST APIs* for those collections automatically. What is the best way?

1. Using Node/express framework preferably
2. Java at backend

I am using **TypeORM** which creates database & crud from schema. But I am looking for other way round

I am also aware of **JHipster** which can create entities and corresponding collections if we define schema in **JHipster** way.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Loopback](https://loopback.io/) in the past to create REST APIs. It takes care of the heavy lifting for you so you end up writing little or no code at all. It also allows you to access data from MySQL, MongoDB and REST APIs just to name a few.

Here's the tutorial I used to build my Loopback application - https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/let-loopback-do-it-a-walkthrough-of-the-node-api-framework-you-ve-been-dreaming-of

Comment: Thanks

How stable it is (v3.x)? I reviewed and found it quite interesting and easy to use. However once it go into production and load/usage increase, does it have any known performance issues ?